# How to unit test ZipOutputStream in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

I've not done a lot of unit testing and was wondering if someone could help/or guide me how to unit test the following source:

```
public byte[] zipBytes(String filename, byte[] content) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
    entry.setSize(content.length);
    zos.putNextEntry(entry);
    zos.write(content);
    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to use etalon byte[]

Comment: @talex Just out of curiosity, why should I use etalon byte[]?

Comment: It is easiest way. You create zip file for fixed context. Check with some util that file wellformed and contains exactly what you need. And then compare result of your method with this file.

Comment: @Simple-Solution could you please put your solution here, ? i am really interessted how did you solve it, because right now i have the same problem of how to testing it properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

1. You take some data and zip it in a trusted, known-to-be-working way. In your unit test, you zip the same data and compare the output with the known-to-be-correct output.
2. Or you could invoke a known-to-be-working unzip method in your unit test to verify whether the zipped data can be unzipped and results in the same data as the original.

Number 1 is probably the most correct one, if you can trust the zip functionality to always output the same data. Number 2 depends on your having a trusted unzip functionality that you don't need to unit test as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could just zip a known string and confirm that the number of bytes in the output is less than the number of bytes in the string, i.e. that it has done some compression.

By checking the exact bytes produced by zipBytes, your unit test is 'leaning' towards unit testing the ZipOutputStream functionality rather than your usage of it.

If you have an opposite method 'unzipBytes', you could confirm you are correctly using both by pushing a known string into zipBytes, pushing the result into unzipBytes and confirming that it is the same as the test string.

If you don't then, in the unit test you could perform the manual steps of creating a ZipInputStream and confirming that there is an entry and it's size conforms to the original length of the bytes/string and when read from equals the same bytes used to test zipBytes.

Otherwise, @Erwin's answer is what you need to do.